# missing MODULE_LICENSE() when two module using same object file

Tags: makefile, linux-kernel

I have two files:
`main.c` will become module `calc`, it will use API in `expression.c`.
`livepatch-calc.c` will become module `livepatch-calc`.

I have following makefile and work well

```sh
obj-m += calc.o
obj-m += livepatch-calc.o
calc-objs += main.o expression.o
ccflags-y := -std=gnu99 -Wno-declaration-after-statement
```

Currently, I need call `expression`'s API in `livepatch-calc.c`. So, I have new makefile like:

```sh
obj-m += calc.o
obj-m += livepatch-calc.o
calc-objs += main.o expression.o
livepatch-calc-objs += expression.o
ccflags-y := -std=gnu99 -Wno-declaration-after-statement
```

Unfortunately, when I make it. Warning message show up:

> WARNING: modpost: missing MODULE_LICENSE() in ..../livepatch-calc.o

I wondering are there anything wrong in my makefile?

Comment: You haven't given us [enough information to be sure](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but try `livepatch-calc-objs += livepatch-calc.o expression.o`

Comment: @Beta, perhaps, `livepatch-calc` (resulting name) should be different to all object files it is built from.

Comment: @Oandriy, u'r right. name of object file should be different from be built. Do u know the reason? Thanks!